# Continuation after Excel File Import Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ssis

Probably a basic SSIS question ...

I have a Loop Container which loops over a directory of Excel File and imports and moves each individual file to another folder ( About 380 Excel Files).

Please no comments about not using a robust file format for importing that volume of files in SSIS, as I completely agree.

The problem I have is that many of the Excel Files, about 80 had Excel File import Errors and I had to stop , put the problem file aside and restart about 20 times before I could identify all the problem Excel files to manually fix.

So is there any way I can get the process to skip problem Excel Files that cause the Excel source in the Data Flow to go RED, and just process all the good files?

Finding a solution to this will save me at least an hour when running the process ?

This is SSIS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the task property ForceExecutionResult to Success.
If you are looking for something more [robust](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3575/continue-a-foreach-loop-after-an-error-in-a-sql-server-integration-services-package/)

Comment: I will test this . What then happens to the failed files ? How can I only move the processed files in the same loop and not the failed files ? Maybe I can check for the Site in the Import table and take that down another path. Hmmmmm